# Compute Diffie-Hellman key pair and shared secret in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, diffie-hellman, key-pair, shared-secret

I need on iOS with Swift to:

- **Generate a Diffie–Hellman key pair** with a pre-agreed modulus P and a base G
- **Compute a shared secret** with a local private key, a remote public key and pre-agreed modulus P

And this **without** Elliptic-curve Diffie–Hellman (ECDH).

I wrote this code using [BigInt repository](https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt).

```
/// Diffie–Hellman key pair
struct DHKeyPair {
    var privateKey: Data
    var publicKey: Data

    init(privateKey: Data, publicKey: Data) {
        self.privateKey = privateKey
        self.publicKey = publicKey
    }
}

/// Generate a Diffie–Hellman key pair
///
/// - Parameter modulus: Diffie-Hellman modulus P
/// - Parameter base: Diffie-Hellman base G
/// - Returns: DH key pair, or nil on error
static func generateDhKeyPair(modulus: Data, base: Data) -> DHKeyPair? {
    // Modulus
    let modulusBigUInt = BigUInt(modulus)

    // Base
    let baseBigUInt = BigUInt(base)

    // Generate random private key
    guard let privateKey = Crypto.randomBytes(length: 512) else {
        return nil
    }
    let privateKeyBigUInt = BigUInt(privateKey)

    // Compute public key
    let publicKeyBigUInt = baseBigUInt.power(privateKeyBigUInt, modulus: modulusBigUInt)
    var publicKey = publicKeyBigUInt.serialize()

    // Set Diffie-Hellman key pair
    let dhKeypair = DHKeyPair(privateKey: privateKey, publicKey: publicKey)

    return dhKeypair
}

/// Compute a shared secret based on local pair key (public/private) and remote public key
///
/// - Parameter privateKey: Private key
/// - Parameter remotePublicKey: Remote public key
/// - Parameter modulus: Diffie-Hellman modulus P
/// - Returns: the computed shared secret
static func computeSharedSecret(privateKey: Data, remotePublicKey: Data, modulus: Data) -> Data {
    // Private key
    let privateKeyBigUInt = BigUInt(privateKey)

    // Remote public key
    let remotePublicKeyBigUInt = BigUInt(remotePublicKey)

    // Modulus
    let modulusBigUInt = BigUInt(modulus)

    // Compute shared secret
    let sharedSecretBigUInt = remotePublicKeyBigUInt.power(privateKeyBigUInt, modulus: modulusBigUInt)
    var sharedSecret = sharedSecretBigUInt.serialize()

    return sharedSecret
}
```

It's well working but **it takes too long**, about 50 seconds to generate the key pair, and the same to compute the shared secret. This is because of the [BigUInt modular exponentiation function](https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt/blob/114862bdaca21974d9587ec41421fb23b302c309/Sources/Exponentiation.swift#L52) (see [doc](http://attaswift.github.io/BigInt/Structs/BigUInt.html#/s:6BigInt0A4UIntV5power_7modulusA2C_ACtF)).

I couldn't find anything for these operations in the [Keys documentation of the API for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys).

So how can I do these Diffie-Hellman operations faster? Can it be done also with Swift API?

PS: we've the [same function on the JDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/DHKeyAgreement.java#L318) which takes just a few seconds.

**EDIT 1:**

These 2 operations take about 4 seconds with a build in release, which is acceptable. But the execution time is still too long in debug (on a real device or a simulator), and also the unit tests are commented because the execution time is too long when running the unit tests.